# How to output text in multiline

Tags: powershell, user-interface, input, output

I am fighting with outputting text file and getting file content in exactly the same way as it was provided by the user. I tried to find an answer but the only thing I can find is how to change multiline into one string which is quite the opposite I need.

How to ensure that input provided by the user in multiline will not be altered to single line in PowerShell?

---

**Details:**

In inputbox I provide details in *multiline*:

[image]

PowerShell saves the output in **one** line:

[image]

I want PowerShell to save multiline input and then show multiline output.

Here is the code:

```
function Notes
{

$var = $Users.Text 
$var | Out-File C:\Users\A570654\Desktop\users.txt
$var = Get-Content C:\Users\A570654\Desktop\users.txt


Set-Content -Path C:\Users\A570654\Desktop\notes.txt "*************************************************
$var
*************************************************"


Invoke-Item -Path C:\Users\A570654\Desktop\notes.txt
}

############################## FORMS #######################################

$Users = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$Users.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.size(470,85)
$Users.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100)
$Users.MultiLine = $true
$Users.AutoSize = $true
$Users.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$users.AcceptsTab

$form = New-Object system.windows.forms.form
$form.size = New-Object system.drawing.size(600,600)

$button = New-Object system.windows.forms.button
$button.text = "Get Notes"
$button.Add_Click({Notes})


$form.Controls.Add($Users)
$form.Controls.Add($button)
$form.Showdialog()
```

The reason why I decided to save the string in file is that output shows spaces as in picture 2. If I decide not to save output to file and then get its content then string appears in the following format: JohnTomKate.

Answer (score 2):

You are saving the user input to a file and *reload* the content which will give you the current output. So just use the variable without reassigning it:

```
$var = $Users.Text 
$var | Out-File C:\Users\A570654\Desktop\users.txt

Set-Content -Path C:\Users\A570654\Desktop\notes.txt "*************************************************
$var
*************************************************"
```

---

**Output:**

```
*************************************************
John 
Tom 
Kate
*************************************************
```

Comment: Martin,Thanks for response but your solution does not work at all. It does not change how user's input is formatted. Using you solution still gives me: